# Fields interactions in Access

Tags: ms-access

Okay, I got a Access database with 1 table (lets call it sectorDescriptions) who contain two column, one who contain the code of all the sectors of activity and the other who contain the name of the sector of activity. Then I got another table (lets call it... ClientInfo) who contain MUCH MORE column but one of those column which is a dropdown list who contain the code of the sector of activity from the table of sectorDescriptions. Now heres my question, I made a form out of the table ClientInfo and now I want that when the user pick a new sector code from the dropdown list, the box named sector name change to the matching sector name based on the sector code! LOL worst question's formulation ever! Sorry for that but I am tired and I'm not really good in english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your combo box (cboFilter in this example) should have recordset property something like this:
SELECT [sector code], sectorDescriptions FROM sectorDescriptions ORDER BY [sector code];
If you don't want people to see the Description, just set the column width to 0"
On the after update event of your combo box, put something like this:
Me.txtDescription = Me.cboFilter.Column(1)